# Helloworld MFC Application is throwing exception

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am getting an **exception** while running the **helloworld MFC application**. I have created "Desktop Application" and selected "Empty Project" and then added the required code. I also selected "Use MFC as Shared DLL" in project setting. Added CMyApp and CMainWindow class in code. Also added message map. How do I fix this exception?

code:
Hello.h

```
class CMyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
};

class CMainWindow : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    CMainWindow();

protected:
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

Hello.cpp

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include "Hello.h"

BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    m_pMainWnd = new CMainWindow;
    m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
    m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
    return TRUE;
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainWindow,CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CMainWindow::CMainWindow()
{
    Create(NULL,_T("The Hello Application"));

}

void CMainWindow::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    dc.DrawText(_T("Hello MFC"),-1,&rect,DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER);
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Use the MFC App wizard and remove the "Document/view architecture support". This will create all the necessary boiler plate code you need for MFC and which you haven't included in your code.

Answer (score 1):

actually i missed following statement in Hello.cpp.

```
CMyApp myApp;
```

After adding this statement, it works.

Comment: Ok. But why did you do all that yourself? Use the IDE to create an empty project of the relevant type. There is no need to roll out your own in this instance.

Comment: @and To learn to write code you have to write code yourself.

Comment: I get that! I have learnt to use a saw before a band saw. But that was a frame app. Why not a complete sample and talk you through it. Doesn’t matter. But I agree with you 100%.